# Shouldn't the output be 2 2

Tags: c, gdb

```
    int i = 0, j = 1; 
    void func(int *p, int *q) 
    { 
        p = q; //Here the address of p and q are made same. 
      * p = 2; // value @ address pointed by 'p'(which is q) is now set to 2.
    }     
    int main() //Start of Main
    { 
        func(&i, &j); 
        printf("%d %d n", i, j); 
        return 0; 
    }
when address held in p and q are same , i'm not understanding why the output isn't same as well (2 2).
</code>
If i fire up gdb i see the following
(gdb) p &p 
$4 = (int **) 0x7fffffffebc8   <<Actual address of var p                                                                 (gdb) p &q                                                                               
$6 = (int **) 0x7fffffffebc0   << Actual address of var q                                                       (gdb) n                                                                                          17      }                                                                                    
(gdb) p p                                                                                    
$8 = (int *) 0x601040 <j>    << After the func ends its pointing only to 'j'                                                                
(gdb) p q                                                                                    
$9 = (int *) 0x601040 <j>
```

Is this something to do with the stacks being different between `main()` and `func()`?

From what I know the address to point to `'i'` is overridden by `'j'` isn't it?

Can anyone please correct my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

In C, parameters are passed as a copy. So `p` and `q` are copies of the original addresses `&i` and `&j` passed in `func(&i, &j);`. So when you do this:

```
p = q; //Here the address of p and q are made same.
```

`p` and `q` are indeed the same now, both the address of `j`. So when you do this:

```
* p = 2; // value @ address pointed by 'p'(which is q) is now set to 2.
```

It sets what `p` points to (which is `j`) to `2`.

`i` is not modified at all by this, so it's still `0`. You passed the address of `i` as parameter `p`, but you immediately discarded that address when you set `p` to `q` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Initially at Global scope, i and j values are 0 and 1 respectively. When function calling the address(location) of i and j passed.

```
Here, 
*p = i,
*q = j;
```

In function callee, p and q holds the address of i and j .
When assigning, `p = q`. **q is assigned to p, which means p also holds the address of j**. And then, `*p = 2` set the value for the address pointed by p. p is currently pointed to j.So while printing j value is 2, and i values remains same. In this scenario, we don't have any pointer that pointed to i. We only modify the i value through i alone.

Hope this will helps:)

Comment: Understood. Thank you guys

Comment: Please make sure your question was answered.